# Extract SWF file from PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, flash

I have implemented adding swf files to pdf using iTextsharp, and my question is, is it possible to do the reverse engineering, for example if I give pdf as input, I have to get swf files from it, if yes how I can do that?

Any idea of how to start, would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Raghu.M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working example that takes this embedded pdf here (first one I found):

http://www.opf-labs.org/format-corpus/pdfCabinetOfHorrors/fileAttachment.pdf

And extracts the embedded files, in this case a KSBASE.WQ2 file.

```
    public static void ExtractAttachments(String src, String dir)
    {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", dir, src));
        PdfDictionary root = reader.Catalog;
        PdfDictionary names = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
        PdfDictionary embedded = names.GetAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
        PdfArray filespecs = embedded.GetAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
        for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.Size; )
        {
            ExtractAttachment(reader, dir, filespecs.GetAsString(i++),
            filespecs.GetAsDict(i++));

        }
    }

    protected static void ExtractAttachment(PdfReader reader, string dir, PdfString name, PdfDictionary filespec)
    {
        PRStream stream;
        FileStream fos;
        String filename;
        PdfDictionary refs = filespec.GetAsDict(PdfName.EF);
        foreach(PdfName key in refs.Keys) {
            stream = (PRStream)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(refs.GetAsIndirectObject(key));
            filename = filespec.GetAsString(key).ToString();
            // here you can do an filename.Contains(".swf) check
            var fileBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);
            File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", dir, filename), fileBytes);
            }
        }
```

You would call this as follows:

```
var dir = "C:\\temp\\PdfExtract";
ExtractAttachments("fileAttachment.pdf", dir);
```

You can simply add a `filename.Contains(".swf)` check around the file names before extracting.

**Update**

Ok, this is how I would figure it out if the above approach did not work.

The files must be located in a different place within the catalog, without seeing the file this is how I would approach it.

I would add a breakpoint after root is resolved then step into it to see if I could find where the swf files are.

If you look into `root.Keys` you will see what the `Catalog` contains.

[image: root.Keys]

To retreive any dictionary objects you can use the `GetAsDict` method passing in a `PdfName` which matches.

Stepping down a level futher you can see that it contains the `EmbeddedFiles` and so forth.

[image]

There are several `PdfName` names, there is even a Flash one.

As the structure of any document can be different it will just be a case of investigating the structure and using the correct parameter's to `GetAsDict` in order to read the files.

Comment: PdfDictionary names = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
here names is null, so I am getting null reference error in 
PdfDictionary embedded = names.GetAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);

Comment: Let me tell you one thing, the swf file is not like an attachment to pdf it is embedded swf of pdf. I hope I am making sense....

Comment: Have you tried the code with the linked PDF in the answer? That one definitely works. It would really depend on the PDF that you are reading too. Can you put a link to the actual file in your question?

Comment: It is working fine with your pdf but not working with my pdf, is this a limitation? how can I resolve this, I am getting names as null

Comment: I would put a break point in the code before then and see what is in root via the debugger. There may be another way of getting to it. I can't really work it out unfortunately without seeing the produced pdf and even then sometimes it can be difficult.

Comment: ok..FYI the swf file is not like an attachment that is actually embedded in pdf so is it possible to extract that?

Comment: How do I attach PDF, I don't think that is possible in SOF

Comment: It's the only way that I know, it can depend on what is in the file, try this intead: PdfDictionary names = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.KIDS); As far as I know attachments are still classed as embedded as this is used to read them out. names.GetAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES); Without being able to debug I can't really tell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47643/discussion-between-raghurocks-and-hutchonoid)

Comment: FYI , I have added my pdf in the discussion board